# Unable to extract Product images using Scrapy

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to extract product images using scrapy from this link

https://bbdealz.com/product/1000pcs-jigsaw-puzzle-7550cm-with-storage-bag-wooden-paper-puzzles-educational-toys-for-children-bedroom-decoration-stickers/

Here is my code

```
'img': response.css('figure.woocommerce-product-gallery__image a::attr("href")').getall(),
```

But it return empty. How to get all the images with comma seprated using scrapy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using `xpath[contains()]`

I have tested that this works:

```
response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'woocommerce-product-gallery__image')]/a/@href").getall()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Please tell me how to detect the xpath ?

Comment: you can get the xpath using the chrome dev tools.  you just right click on any element and select copy xpath